# Scala 2.12: Unable to use unapply in extractor object

Tags: scala

I am following through Scala Tour provided on [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org). I am stuck at the extractor objects tutorial: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html

Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
object IdGenerator {
  private val id: AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger
  def apply(name: String): String = id.incrementAndGet + "--" + name
  def unapply(genID: String): Option[String] = {
    val idParts = genID.split("--")
    if (idParts.head.nonEmpty && idParts.tail.nonEmpty)
      Some(idParts(0))
    else
      None
  }
}

println(IdGenerator("ABC"))
println(IdGenerator("DEF"))
println(IdGenerator("XYZ"))

IdGenerator(idName) = IdGenerator("ABC")
println(idName)
println(IdGenerator.unapply(IdGenerator("ABC")))
```

Here is the error:

```
D:\MyApps\ScalaPrac\helloworld\hello\src\main\scala\example\Hello.scala:68:5: value update is not a member of object example.IdGenerator
IdGenerator(idName) = IdGenerator("ABC")
```

It says that **value update is not a member of object**. Sure, it isn't. But I am not asking it to look for `update` method, I want it to look for `unapply` instead.

Comment: I suppose you forgot to put `val` before `IdGenerator(idName) = IdGenerator("ABC")`

Comment: This wording from that page could be improved; instead of "assign" it should say "initialize": "The unapply method can also be used to assign a value." E.g., "Since a value definition can use a pattern to initialize a variable, an extractor can be used as the pattern to introduce the new variable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IdGenerator(idName) = x` looks like an assignment, but it actually is syntax sugar for `IdGenerator.update(idName, x)`. That explains the error message you get.

You need to use the `val` keyword to extract `idName`:

```
val IdGenerator(idName) = IdGenerator("ABC")
```